# Typescript error: Argument type is not assignable to parameter type, but they are the same

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, interface

Please tell me, why is there an error?

```
interface IAction {
  readonly type: "GET_CURRENT_DATE" | "SET_CURRENT_DATE";
}
interface IDispatch {
    (param: IAction): void;
}
export const getCurrentDate = () => (dispatch: IDispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: "GET_CURRENT_DATE"});
};
```

**ERROR: Argument type {type:string} is not assignable to parameter type IAction**

But {type: "GET_CURRENT_DATE"} the same as IAction

UPD: 
in package.json -> "typescript": "^2.6.2". 
Compile with webpack "ts-loader" gives also no errors, but in my IDE (PhpStorm 2017.3) I see this error message.

Comment: That exact code gives no error in [the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=interface%20IAction%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20type%3A%20%22GET_CURRENT_DATE%22%20%7C%20%22SET_CURRENT_DATE%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20IDispatch%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%28param%3A%20IAction%29%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20const%20getCurrentDate%20%3D%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20%28dispatch%3A%20IDispatch%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch%28%7Btype%3A%20%22GET_CURRENT_DATE%22%7D%29%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B).  What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: "typescript": "^2.6.2". Compile with webpack ts-loader gives also no errors, but in my IDE (PhpStorm 2017.3) I see this error message.

Comment: Generally you should make sure your question is [complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so others can help you.  For now I'd suggest hunting down how your IDE runs the TypeScript compiler, because your problem is likely to be an issue with configuration rather than the code.

Comment: You're right. I've done it with change this setting in "Settings | Language and Frameworks | Typescript" And change checked "Angular Language Service" to "Also for projects without tsconfig.json". Now it works

Answer (score 0):

I've done it with change this setting in my IDE (WebStorm) "Settings | Language and Frameworks | Typescript" And change checked "TypeScript Language Service" to "Also for projects without tsconfig.json". Now it works